# A wizard with spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, wizard

I'm developping a web application with Spring MVC, and i need to develop a new model as a wizard; first i have to load a file and extract informations from this file, after i have to edit these informations, and doing other operations, and i have to finish the process by doing other traitement. I'm looking on internet i found `AbstractWizardFormController` but when i saw, i think that we can't do a process in pages, there is just Finish process.

Comment: That's not really a question...

Comment: I think this leads up to a good question: how can one do intermediate page processing with an AbstractWizardFormController?

Answer (score 0):

Use WebFlow on top of MVC - its built for wizards.  Here's an example: http://realworldagile.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/modal-wizard-forms-using-spring-webflow-2-0-8-and-richfaces/